# Jumping to a specific SKNode in node hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sknode

I have noticed that the SKNode methods `children` and `childNodeWithName:` as the name implies only return results from the children directly below the queried node. i.e. `[root children];` will return an `NSArray` containing the nodes `@[CUBE1, CUBE2, CUBE3]`.

In the diagram below I want to get from the ROOT (SKScene) level down to SPHERE2 so that I can quickly access that nodes children. I was hoping that `[root childNodeWithName:@"SPHERE2"];` would traverse the whole hierarchy and return a pointer to SPHERE2

[image]

**MY QUESTION:** Is there something that I have missed that will let me jump into a node tree at a specified point (i.e. using the node name)

I could use properties to store pointers to important positions in the tree and then use these to access and process any child nodes, so that is an option ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the advanced search syntax described in the [SKNode documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKNode), under Advanced Searches.

This will search the entire node tree recursively for a node named "SPHERE2", starting from the root node:

```
SKNode* sphere2 = [root childNodeWithName:@"//SPHERE2"];
```

If you know the path to a specific node, you can also use that quite easily:

```
SKNode* triangle3 = [root childNodeWithName:@"/CUBE3/SPHERE2/TRIANGLE3"];
```

It should be noted if you need those nodes often, you should cache them in a `__weak` ivar or `weak` property because searching nodes by name takes a little while.

Comment: Perfect, I don't know how I missed that I have supposedly read all that. Much appreciated Steffen, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: OK, but how to find all children named "MyChildren" of the node "Me" while we don't know where "Me" is placed in the tree?

Comment: You would use "//Me/MyChildren" to search the entire tree for nodes named "MyChildren" that have parent named "Me".